# Как вложить класс в метод?

Tags: java

Есть кусок кода на java

```
final List<Advertisement> advertisements = new ArrayList<>();
new Object() {
    public void recurse(int i) {
        advertisements.add(storage.list().get(i));
        if (i + 1 < storage.list().size())
            recurse(i + 1);
    }
}.recurse(0);
```

предполагается копирование элементов листа из storage.list() в advertisements таким вот способом, но почему-то по отработке кода лист пустой, что может быть не так?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. "почему-то по отработке кода лист пустой".... и? Что происходит, когда лист пустой? Т.е. в чем проблема?

Comment: что хранится в storage? вы уверены, что `i + 1 < storage.list().size()` это выражение на первой итерации является истинным? как вы поняли что в итоге он пустой? даже если вышеупомянутое выражение возвращает false, то в ваш список должен добавиться как минимум один элемент, либо должна быть ошибка (если `storage.list().size() == 0`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сложно сказать, почему у Вас что-то не работает. Возможно, проблема в другом коде, который мы не видим. Однако, на одну неточность можно указать сразу - всегда выполняется `storage.list().get(0)` без проверки списка на непустоту. Это может привести к исключению.

Если же рассматривать идею, то она вполне работоспособная. Вот немного изменённый работающий код:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        list1.add("String 1");
        list1.add("String 2");
        list1.add("String 3");

        new Object() {
            public void recurse(final int i) {
                if (i < list1.size()) {
                    list2.add(list1.get(i));
                    recurse(i + 1);
                }
            }
        }.recurse(0);

        System.out.println("List 1:");
        for (final String s : list1)
            System.out.println("\t" + s);

        System.out.println("List 2:");
        for (final String s : list2)
            System.out.println("\t" + s);
    }
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
List 1:
        String 1
        String 2
        String 3
List 2:
        String 1
        String 2
        String 3
```

Comment: да там основной замысел вообще проверить анонимный класс, поэтому не стал нагромождать его проверками, и по умолчанию лист-донор содержит записи, но собственно уже все разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Все разобрался, собственно грешил на анонимный класс, но сделал вот такую проверку

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(p, 5, 6, 7);
        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        new Object() {
            public void recurse(int i) {
                list.add(p.get(i));
                if (i + 1 < p.size())
                    recurse(i + 1);
            }
        }.recurse(0);
        for(int i : list) System.out.println(i);
    }
```

и она отработал на ура. Потом продолжил реализацию своего кода, получился такой говнокод

```
final List<Advertisement> advertisements = new ArrayList<>();
new Object() {
    public void recurse(int duration) {recurse(duration, 0);}

    public void recurse(int duration, int i) {
       if(storage.list().get(i).getDuration() <= duration)
          advertisements.add(storage.list().get(i));
       if (i + 1 < storage.list().size())
          recurse(storage.list().get(i).getDuration() <= duration ?
                   duration - storage.list().get(i).getDuration() :
                   duration, i + 1);
    }
}.recurse(timeSeconds);
```

но хотя бы рабочий и меня пока устраивает.

Спасибо всем за помощь и простите если не так выразился в описании